# Difference between 仮、一時的、臨時 when expressing "temporary"

Tags: word-choice, words, nuances

All of these words express "temporary" but I can't understand the difference and in which contexts each are used.

For example:

> **仮**の包帯 A temporary bandage
>
> **一時的**な住宅 A temporary residence
>
> **臨時**列車 A temporary train

Are they all interchangeable in these sentences? What is the difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- **仮の** is more like *tentative*. It describes something is to be replaced by an official/final/permanent one in the future. For example 仮のタイトル is a tentative title.
- **臨時(の)** is an antonym of *regular*, *periodic* or *scheduled*. It describes something is an additional, unscheduled or "ad-hoc" one.
- **一時的** is *temporary*. It describes something is not permanent.

For example, in a job hunting context:

- **仮(の)採用**: You are tentatively or unofficially hired for evaluation. You may be fired if your performance turned out to be poor.
- **臨時(の)採用**: You are hired outside the regular/scheduled recruitment process. The employment relationship will be permanent unless otherwise mentioned.
- **一時的(な)採用**: Temporary employment. Your employment will finish after a certain period.